# Make classes implementing Interface raise event

Tags: c#-4.0, interface, event-handling

I have an interface where I define some event like:

```
public event EventHandler<CustomEventArgs> MyCustomEvent;
```

Now I want that any class that Implements my interface actually raise this event.

Is there any way to this or should I have to go via abstract base class and provide with minimal implementation?

Comment: If you asked me, I'd say that having the event there in the first place implies that the implementer would raise the event when needed. Exactly how it is raised should be to the implementer's discretion and shouldn't be "forced" upon by requiring a method meant to raise it (and certainly not publicly). It's standard practice to define a protected method meant to make raising it easier. You could do the same, otherwise you shouldn't do anything else afterwards.

Comment: If you want to enforce it, consider creating an abstract class which implements the contract and raises the event within an overridable method.  The consuming classes can then inherit the base class automatically implementing the event code you want, with the option to override the method if they require custom implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces declare structure NOT a behaviour, so there is no possibility to do it using interface and I think this is very good ;)

Only one way I see is creating an abstract class which implements [Template Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) pattern and raise event as required. But I must agree with Jeff Mercado's comment that this is not a good idea to force such obligations.